# How to change prefix variable during building gRPC since no configure is provided?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, grpc

I am compiling `gRPC` program and want to change [prefix](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/f37dfda1c3f0428995d67cb82c6fbcada7260e84/Makefile#L232) from "`/usr/local`" to "`/usr`":

```
prefix ?= /usr/local
```

I have tried both "`prefix=/usr make`" and "`make prefix=/usr`" methods, but unfortunately, they seems don't work. So now I can figure out `2` methods:

(1) Modify `Makefile` directly:

```
  prefix = /usr
```

(2) Change `prefix` during installation:

```
make prefix=/usr install
```

Because there is no `configure` program provided, is there any method to change `prefix` during make process?

Comment: `make prefix=/usr` is supposed to work. Why not just edit the makefile?

Comment: The change you want to make seems wrong. `/usr/include` is for headers (`*.h` files), why put them somewhere else?

Comment: @reinierpost `make prefix=/usr` doesn't work. And I have modified the OP to fix typo.

Comment: @NanXiao *they seems don't work* is not enough. Please provide more information or, better, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet After using `make prefix=/usr`, it still install in `/usr/local`, and seems don't take effect at least on my `ArchLinux`, thx!

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to provide the "prefix" variable during both the "make" and "make install" steps. So the right solution is either to do:

```
export prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

or

```
make prefix=/usr
make install prefix=/usr
```

Comment: Only the second approach will work. Environment variables don't override assignments in makefile.

Comment: That would be true, if this was a normal assignment. However in gRPC's Makefile, prefix is assigned using ?=, meaning assign if it doesn't already exist (from the environment or any other mean).

Example:

`$ cat Makefile`
`foo ?= "bar"`
`all:`
`@echo "$(foo)"`
`$ foo=override make`
`override`